# Thematic charts on leaflet

Tags: leaflet, visualisation, chart

In GIS charts are a part of good visualisation , I wonder if I can show a bar chart for example of my ON , OFF passangers in some Bus line here my plunker example [my example](http://plnkr.co/edit/sAq3KTd2ayGt2HOFH7Nz?p=preview) each stop nodes point has information of ON ; OFF value in my Geojson

---

The leaflet data visualization DFV is awesome I edited the last example and showed ON OFF passengers in each stop in the Bus line
here the example [Charts in Leaflet](http://plnkr.co/edit/sAq3KTd2ayGt2HOFH7Nz?p=preview)

Comment: The answer to "I wonder if I can..." is probably "[yes](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/questions-with-yes-or-no-answers.html)". There are lots and lots of ways to visualize bus traffic (see http://interaktiv.tagesanzeiger.ch/2016/bus3132/ and http://www.fastcoexist.com/1681868/3-creative-ways-to-visualize-urban-public-transportation, for example), but you are not specifying any details. What kind of visualization are you trying to achieve? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an extension of Leaflet Data Visualization Framework [Leaflet Visualisation](https://github.com/humangeo/leaflet-dvf)
specially for charts all types of charts